# Matlab: how to call a function

Tags: matlab

This is my function

```
function [mean,stdev] = stat(x)
n = length(x);
mean = sum(x)/n;
stdev = sqrt(sum((x-mean).^2/n));
```

and I called

> > [mean stdev] = stat([12.7 45.4 98.9 26.6 53/1])
> >         ??? Undefined function or method 'stat' for input arguments of type 'double'.

I also tried

> > mean,stdev = stat([12.7 45.4 98.9 26.6 53/1])
> >         ??? Input argument "x" is undefined.
> >       Error in ==> mean at 30
> >       y = sum(x,dim)/size(x,dim);

Both of them are wrong and I cannot figure out why.

Could you please help me =] Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you get if you type `which stat` ?

Comment: /mnt/nfs/netapp2/students/xinyjiang/Desktop/MATH72 HW/stat.m

Comment: That's good; you don't have another function shadowing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks fine to me, therefore I assume that your Matlab "Current Directory" is not the same directory where your function lives.

Another reason might be that the file in which this function exists does not have the same as this function. In order for Matlab to know that this function exists, it has to live in a separate file called stat.m (note how file name is the same as the function name).

Comment: Thanks. The name of my file is stat.m. I think this is not where the problem is

Comment: And what do you mean by the "Current Directory" is not the same directory?? I'm not understand~

Comment: @user996050 In Matlab, if you go to Window -> Current Folder, you will see the folder you are currently in. Your file much be in that same folder. Otherwise, navigate to that folder and try again.